# prevent draggable div's from eclipsing each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am developing a drag and drop calendar for my website. whereby the user can drag existing date blocks to different times and days. What I'm having trouble with is finding a relativly simple way of figuring out if, when the block is dropped(on the mouse-up event) whether the block partially or totally eclipses an existing date block, in which case the block should move back to it's mouse-down position.Basically I need to find a way to map all the available free area inside the container div(that is all areas where date blocks are not positioned) and if the whole of the dragged div does not exceed this area then allow the drop otherwise move it back to it's mouse-down position. Any Ideas much appreciated. here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D8xCC/) where you can see what I have so far. and the code:

```
  $('.date').resizable({handles: 's', containment: 'parent'});
  $('.date').draggable({containment: 'parent'});

  $('.date').mousedown(function(){ 

        $(this).css('z-index','1');
    });

   $('.date').mouseup(function(){

   $(this).css('z-index','0');

      var leftPosAM = Number($(this).css('left').slice(0,-2));
      var weekBlock =  Math.round(leftPosAM/100)*100;

      $(this).css('left',(weekBlock) + "px")
 });
```

Comment: How about checking out jqueryUI's revert position, listed under "draggable"? http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#revert

Comment: One way is to check X- and Y-distance of center points between dropped/resized element and other elements. Here's a [not deeply tested fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5t6t/1/).